# Mapbox GL symbol animation

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I want to create animation effect on the mapbox GL symbol. Such as, show the icons like dropping from the sky then land on the map. Does the current API support that? If not, any suggestions which class should I modify?

Comment: Are you using Mapbox-GL or MapboxGL-JS? They're very different libraries...

Comment: @SteveBennett
I'm using MapboxGL-JS